# Unable To Convert XML String to Java Object

Tags: java

I am Trying to unmarshal XML String to Java Object.
But I am unable to do it.
I am getting null in response.
Looking for help.
Tried multiple things on the web.

```
    private static void unmarshallStringToObj(String xmlString) throws JAXBException {

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlString);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ApiResponse.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        ApiResponse response = (ApiResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
        System.out.println(response);
        
    }
```

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "ERROR")
public class ApiResponse {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "ERROR")
    private String ERROR;

// getters and setters and constructors
```

This is input XML String
`<ERROR>The specified engine does not exist!</ERROR>`

This is output in the console
`ApiResponse [ERROR=null]`

Comment: Your code describes xml that looks like this: `<ERROR><ERROR>value</ERROR></ERROR>`. Both the root element and the string element inside of it are named `ERROR`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ERROR")
public class ErrorString {
   @XmlValue
   String value;
}

JAXBContext jbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ErrorString.class);
ErrorString myString = (ErrorString) jbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(...);
```

try getting XML element in this way, it will work.